# Phrasing an apology/ correcting possible misunderstanding

Tags: professionalism, communication, email, unprofessional-behavior, relationships

A couple of weeks ago I met a highly respected person in my field working in a C-suite position, during the smoking time outside, we chatted a bit, and he was interested in what do I have to offer, so we agreed on keeping in touch.

A few days ago I received an email from him inviting me for lunch, we exchanged few emails, he was replying quickly and everything was on the right track. until one reply I sent that cutted the flow.

Reading my email again, I saw that I did quit some mistakes:

1. in the greeting I went for "hey" without mentioning his name or
   anything else.
2. No sign-off whatsoever (really bad)
3. last, basically I misread his email, so my reply was reversed, exmple:
   him: "if available, then at 8, if not, then at 10" me: "I'm
   available, 10 would be good for me".

I sent an email after few hours (about 10pm), asking him to excuse me to misreading his email, and I corrected my response "excuse me, I'm available at 8, would be great meeting you again... etc.", but this email went without reply.

Now I feel that I communicated disrespect/rudeness or abruptness; *something like: "I don't have time to write you a proper email"*, which is not my intention, and I don't know how to fix it anymore.

Comment: Is this chief officer someone at your office? Can't you just confront him and apologize in person? Or are you able to call him? I don't see any indication of rudeness but I do see some casual behavior.

Comment: @KingDuken, no I don't work for them. and calling him to apologize may be a "too much" act - I believe, especially if he percieved my email as just a casual behavior. thank you anyways

Answer (score 5):

All you can do is wait for a response.  I don't see anything disrespectful in that exchange, and it was a good thing that you sent a followup clarification.

1. If he's a "highly respected person in the field", I'm willing to bet he's simply a busy guy.   Maybe he has a fire to put out and has't had a chance to respond.
2. If he's that sensitive to a miscommunication, then you likely wouldn't get along very well with him and he'd likely storm out of the restaurant in anger when you innocently mispronounced an item on a menu or didn't hold the chopsticks correctly or something.

Bottom line is, and don't take this the wrong way, but don't act like a smitten 14 year old girl wondering why little Johnny isn't calling her.    If this guy is reasonable and wants to meet with you, you'll hear from him.

Comment: It may be what you said, and it's just my anxiety kicking in. 
My thought was that my slightly inappropriate response would indicate something like: "I don't have time to write you a proper email" or something similiar, and that can be percieved as rude or abrupt.
Anyways, It's always valuabe to get an outer perspective, thank you for giving yours!

Comment: I would have upvoted this answer, but then I saw the 14 year old part. Really? Is this your usual way of giving advice?

Comment: It made a point.   Act like an adult.   Be professional.

Comment: @Keith well, I think I'm "acting" like an adult here, just asking for an extra thoughts; and my concerns are legit based on the reasoning I made.

Comment: Don't think too much into it.    Good grief.

Comment: @Keith It didn't just make a point, it was insulting and hence unncessary. There's a difference. You should stop acting like you've got a fork stuck up your butt. ← see, that makes a point too, but it's also insulting, and should have been left out.

Comment: If that's how I'm acting, it's a good analogy.    Your point?